# Apache Tomcat Server failure

Tags: ssl, tomcat

I'm trying to set up Apache Tomcat 6 with SSL and once I edited the server.xml file to include the following definitions the server started to fail as soon as I hit startup.bat:

UPDATE: I fixed the last problem because of a faulty line in server.xml and now tomcat seems to be starting up. However now when I go to port 8445 to check if my ssl is working, there is no splash page that I can see and instead there are 5 checkboxes(ballot boxes to be specific) that are displayed on an empty page. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this or if this is even a problem?

I posted my logs just in case they are needed, but they seem to show no problems:

```
Jul 05, 2012 2:18:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;.
Jul 05, 2012 2:18:31 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jul 05, 2012 2:18:31 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8445
Jul 05, 2012 2:18:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1468 ms
Jul 05, 2012 2:18:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 05, 2012 2:18:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
Jul 05, 2012 2:18:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor host-manager.xml
Jul 05, 2012 2:18:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
Jul 05, 2012 2:18:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
Jul 05, 2012 2:18:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
Jul 05, 2012 2:18:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
Jul 05, 2012 2:18:32 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jul 05, 2012 2:18:32 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8445
Jul 05, 2012 2:18:32 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Jul 05, 2012 2:18:32 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/40  config=null
Jul 05, 2012 2:18:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1058 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an XML error.

> SEVERE: Parse Fatal Error at line 91 column 2: The content of elements
>   must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId:
>   file://C/tomcat6/conf/server.xml; lineNumber: 91; columnNumber: 2; The
>   content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or
>   markup.

Find a good XML editor, one that understands XML and will validate for you. If you don't have a favorite, try [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org)

Comment: I found out what the problem was, it was this line: <-- Define a SSL Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8445 -->                                          However, now when I open up localhost:8445 on my browser, i get 4 boxes(in text, I think the equiv to ????) on an empty page instead of a tomcat splash page. Do you know what this problem is?

Comment: @KennethOrdona you need to close this question out and ask a new one.

Comment: To clarify `<-- Define a SSL Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8445 -->` is the problem line
it needs to be `<!-- Define a SSL Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8445 -->`